# ChekedListBox with Dictionary as dataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have an xml file looks like this:

```
<Accounts>
  <Account Id="1">
    <UserName>xxx@Hotmail.com</UserName>
    <Password>xxx</Password>
    <AddingDate>06 Mart 2015 Cuma</AddingDate>
    <AccountType>Hotmail</AccountType>
  </Account>
```

I am using a Dictionarylist to keep both username and password values. I display just usernames like this:

```
private void AddAccounts(CheckedListBox chkListBox)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("UserAccounts.xml");
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = doc.Descendants("Account")
        .GroupBy(x => x.Element("UserName"), y => y)
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key.Value, y => y.First().Element("Password").Value);
    foreach (var v in dict)
    {
        checkedListBox1.Items.Add(v.Key);
    }
}
```

Then .I am trying to get this DictionaryList from checkedListBox once the  SelectedIndexChanged event gets fired .Like this way

```
private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("UserAccounts.xml");

    var dataSource = checkedListBox1.DataSource as Dictionary<string, string>;

    if (c != null)
    {
        var password_ = c.Where(x => x.Key.Equals("")).Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

The problem  is that this part below

```
var dataSource = checkedListBox1.DataSource as Dictionary<string, string>;
```

is null . breakpoint never enter   this part

```
if (c != null){}
```

this part.I am pretty sure that AddAccounts function work I tested it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add items to your CheckedListBox and get them back as DataSource.

If you want to set your Dictionary as DataSource of the CheckedListBox you have assign it like this

```
// delete this lines...
//foreach (var v in dict)
//{
//    checkedListBox1.Items.Add(v.Key);
//}

checkedListBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(dict, null);
checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
checkedListBox1.ValueMember = "Key";
```

and in your SelectedIndexChanged event you have to assign dataSource like this

```
var dataSource = checkedListBox1.DataSource as BindingSource;
var dict = dataSource.DataSource as Dictionary<string, string>;
```

Hope this helps!